# chave estrangeira

Tags: php

Estou com problema pra gravar valor null em chave estrangeira. Quando gravo na agenda com com `id_pessoa` em branco, ela grava 0 e nao null. Como posso arrumar isto?

Este eu meu codigo e tabela :

pessoa:

```
id_pessoa int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ds_pessoa varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
agenda:
id_agenda  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
hr_agendamento time(11) DEFAULT NULL,
id_pessoa int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Código php

```
<?php
$hr_agendamento = $_POST['hr_agendamento'];
$id_pessoa = $_POST['id_pessoa'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO agenda (hr_agendamento, id_pessoa)
VALUES ( $hr_agendamento, $id_pessoa)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso ocorre pois se você passa um valor como string vazia em um campo que é `INT`, o MySQL coloca `0`.

Para isso, basta você trabalhar a variável `$id_pessoa` para levar o valor de `NULL` para o MySQL quando a mesma estiver vazia. Ex:

```
$id_pessoa = $_POST['id_pessoa'];
if(empty($id_pessoa)) {
  $id_pessoa = 'NULL';
}
```

Fazendo assim, quando você concatenar a variável na query, ele imprime algo do tipo:

```
INSERT INTO agenda (hr_agendamento, id_pessoa) VALUES ( 'XX:XX', NULL);
```

Comment: obrigado amigo funcionou perfeitamente..